# Mounting USB stick in place of HDD

Tags: mount, symlink, raspberry-pi, raspbian, usb-drive

I'm currently working on a `raspian` automated box. I've connected an HDD Drive to use as a Samba server and the download and temp folder for the transmission client installed.

As the HDD is noisy (and in my room), I wanted to know a few things:

1. Is there a way to check what services are accessing the HDD at a given time (to stop them if I need to `unmount`)? When putting the HDD to sleep (without any services started myself but `samba` using it), it still wakes up about 3-4 minutes after. How can I log `IO` operations to this HDD?
2. Is it possible to `unmount` the HDD then `mount` an always connected USB stick in place of this HDD (i.e. make the path to USB stick be the same as the one to the HDD), so that (after moving all current chunks used by transmission on the HDD to the USB) I can resume those downloads on the USB with transmission not knowing what happened? I've documented, myself, about different possibilities: basic `unmount/mount`, `symlinks`, RAIDs... what would be the best option?